# Compiler fails to find right function overload

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a small base class that defines 3 overloads for a function. Overload A calls overload B which is pure virtual, and its implementation in the derived class calls overload C.

My complete code is as follows:

```
struct Base {
        int func(int a) {return func(a, a+1);}
        int func(int a, int b, int c) {return a+b+c;}
        virtual int func(int a, int b)=0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
        int func(int a, int b);
};

int Derived::func(int a, int b) {
        return func(a,b,a+b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        Derived d;
        d.func(1);
        return 0;
}
```

This code yields the errors:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int Derived::func(int, int)’:
test.cpp:12:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::func(int&, int&, int)’
   12 |  return func(a,b,a+b);
      |                     ^
test.cpp:11:5: note: candidate: ‘virtual int Derived::func(int, int)’
   11 | int Derived::func(int a, int b) {
      |     ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:17:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::func(int)’
   17 |  d.func(1);
      |          ^
test.cpp:11:5: note: candidate: ‘virtual int Derived::func(int, int)’
   11 | int Derived::func(int a, int b) {
      |     ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Why does the compiler fail to find the correct overload twice? (once in the call to overload C in the derived class, and once when calling overload A in the main)

Comment: I think that the overrode `func()` function is hiding the base class overloaded `func`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a function in a derived class with the same name as in the base class, the declaration in the derived class will shadow the functions in the base class.

So in `Derived`, the only visible `func` is the `(int, int)` one.

One easy way to solve this is to pull the base class functions into the overload set with `using`.

```
struct Derived : public Base {
        using Base::func; // All the func overloads are now pulled into Derived's scope
        int func(int a, int b);
};
```